# Timestamp function that has been working reliably just caused EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, swift, timestamp, exc-bad-instruction

I have been using this function to generate a time stamp. I found it somewhere here on Stack Overflow.

```
@objc public class var timestamp: String {
    return "\(Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000))"
}
```

It has been working without issue, but I just got a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION:

```
fatal error: floating point value cannot be converted to Int because it is greater than Int.max
```

As the development of this app is nearing completion it makes me nervous to all of the sudden see it cause a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION. This is running in the Simulator, but I have a valid date and time set.

Any ideas or suggestions or are greatly appreciated. Below is the backtrace.

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x15c4d, 0x04a30393 libswiftCore.dylib`function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> () + 67, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
frame #0: 0x04a30393 libswiftCore.dylib function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> () + 67
* frame #1: 0x00afe0c9 TDTPhotoLib static     
TDTDeviceUtilites.timestamp.getter(self=TDTPhotoLib.TDTDeviceUtilites) + 409 at TDTDeviceUtilites.swift:127
frame #2: 0x00166979 Oilist TDTPaintingViewController.finshedSession(sender=0x7aee0fb0, self=0x7e9d3800) -> () + 169 at TDTPaintingViewController.swift:1370
frame #3: 0x00102896 Oilist TDTOilistMenuPainting.goForward(sender=0x7aee0fb0, self=0x7c218770) -> () + 374 at TDTOilistMenuPainting.swift:149
frame #4: 0x0010290d Oilist @objc TDTOilistMenuPainting.goForward(UIButton!) -> () + 61 at TDTOilistMenuPainting.swift:0
frame #5: 0x018a80b5 libobjc.A.dylib -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
frame #6: 0x0336ee38 UIKit -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 118
frame #7: 0x0336edb7 UIKit -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
frame #8: 0x03512f3b UIKit -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 79
frame #9: 0x035132d4 UIKit -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 433
frame #10: 0x035122c1 UIKit -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 714
frame #11: 0x033ef52e UIKit -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 1095
frame #12: 0x033f05cc UIKit -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1159
frame #13: 0x03391be8 UIKit -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 266
frame #14: 0x03366769 UIKit _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7795
frame #15: 0x02423e5f CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
frame #16: 0x02419aeb CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 523
frame #17: 0x02418f08 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
frame #18: 0x02418846 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
frame #19: 0x0241865b CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #20: 0x07031664 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal + 192
frame #21: 0x070314a1 GraphicsServices GSEventRun + 104
frame #22: 0x0336ceb9 UIKit UIApplicationMain + 160
frame #23: 0x00131ed1 Oilist main + 145 at AppDelegate.swift:14
frame #24: 0x05631a25 libdyld.dylib start + 1
```

Comment: Hmm so I changed the factor from 1000 to 10 and I still had the same EXC_BAD. Removed the multiplier and it works. But if it has been working with 1000, I have no idea why it is failing all the sudden with 10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code will crash on all 32-bit platforms (such as iPhone 4, 5)
because the result of

```
NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
// E.g.: 1464850525047.38
```

does not fit into a 32-bit integer. As a solution, use 64-bit integers:

```
Int64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
```

Alternatively, if the intention is to create a *string* representing
the milliseconds, use string formatting instead of an integer conversion:

```
String(format:"%.0f", NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
```

Comment: Odd, as I thought that I have tested it on an iPhone 5 before. In any event that does seem to do the trick, and going to 64- bit certainly gives it much more headroom, thanks.

Comment: I see what happened now - I accidentally set my target to a 32-bit device. Glad I did, though I am don't think the app will support any 32-bit devices.