# Truncating fractional component of NSTimeInterval?

Tags: swift, nstimeinterval, truncation

I'm new to iOS and Swift and I'm trying to get the current time in milliseconds since the Unix epoch.  I have a global computed variable defined like this:

```
var currentTimeInMs: NSTimeInterval {
    return NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
}
```

The value I get back from this variable contains a fractional component.  For example:

```
1464958907683.18
```

I need to use this value as a JSON parameter to a web request and the API does not like the fractional portion of this value.  Is it possible to truncate this value so I just get back `1464958907683` instead of `1464958907683.18`?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37584700/1187415.

Comment: Thanks very much, Martin.  That's exactly what I needed.