# While creating a String value from timestamp, getting crash [Swift]

Tags: swift, string, date, int

When creating a time timestamp from Date() function app is getting crash rarely, Is it the right way to handle it?

```
let time_stamp = String(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970*1000))
```

The above code is getting crash rarely, in the test flight build.
[image]

Added the log, line number 3216 is the above one.

Comment: Add here also the crash log.

Comment: Do you support 32-bit devices? Then this would be your problem: [Timestamp function that has been working reliably just caused EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584501/timestamp-function-that-has-been-working-reliably-just-caused-exc-bad-instructio).

Comment: The stack backtrace shows that the crash happens on a 32-bit device, so the linked-to Q&A should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, Currently we are supporting 32bit devices, got the answer from you post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't cast to int, go to string directly and avoid the 32bit device length error

```
let time_stamp = String(format:"%.0f", NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of casting you can simply use like this

```
let timeStamp = "\(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970*1000))"
```

Comment: That won't prevent the crash on 32-bit devices.

Answer (score 0):

Just create String directly like this :

```
let time_stamp = "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970*1000)"
```